# Angular 6, subscribe to activateRoute.queryParamMap, WebStorm gives "Promise returned from subscribe is ignored" warning

Tags: angular, webstorm

I have the following code in Angular 6:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";

...

export class someComponent implements OnInit {

  life: string;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(urlParams => this.life = urlParams.get('foo'));
  }

  ...

}
```

I have instantiated `route` from ActivatedRoute, and my goal is to assign the query parameters `foo` from the url to one of my variables called `life`.
However, I am receiving the following warnings(Green curly lines, so I am not sure if they are warnings or errors or something else) on WebStorm:

1. when I hover my mouse to `subscribe` I get `Promise returned from subscribe is ignored`,
2. When I hover my mouse to `urlParams` I get `Argument type (urlParams: any) => void is not assignable to parameter type PushSubscriptionOptionsInit | undefined`

[image: Screenshot for warning 1 and warning 2]

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: `PushSubscriptionOptionsInit` is part of the Push Api.  There shouldn't be anything regarding that in the code you've provided.  I think we're missing some context by only providing partial code.  Can you add your entire service or component code?

Comment: I have updated the code!

Comment: What is your WebStorm version?

Comment: WebStorm 2018.2.2
Build #WS-182.4129.32, built on August 21, 2018

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue that went away after installing all modules (npm i) and refreshing the WebStorm indices (synchronize command on node_modules).

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue in Webstorm with angular 12.

Removal of node_modules and restart of Webstorm didn't help me.

Instead, try to add node_modules in Libraries for JS:

1. Webstorm Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries.
2. Click Add... button
3. Fill in the showed form
4. Wait for IDEA to index the dependencies

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ Ultimate complains about this pattern for me as well.

I think it's an issue with the indexes/types the IDE builds/uses. For some reason it appears to confuse the subscribe method as being from the PushManager interface accessible via the ServiceWorkerRegistration pushManager property.

Two things that work for me:

1. Close your IDE, delete your node_modules, reinstall your packages and open the IDE back up so it will re-index your code and maybe stop complaining
2. Move your anonymous function out of the subscribe call and into a tap operator. See below for that example.

```js
this.route.queryParamMap
  .pipe(
    tap((urlParams: Array<string>): Array<string> => {
      this.life = urlParams.get('foo');
      return urlParams;
    }),
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Answer (score -1):

In Angular (currently on Angular-6) .subscribe() is a method on the Observable type. The Observable type is a utility that asynchronously or synchronously streams data to a variety of components or services that have subscribed to the observable.

```
this._route.paramMap.pipe(
  switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
      this.FID = params.get('id');
      return this._serviceXXX();
    }
  )
).subscribe(data => {
  // then code
});
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?